# Parse time '1hr 30m 4s' as time ahead in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, date-fns

Let's say I have a string `1hr 30m 4s`. How would I use Node.js to parse that string into (obviously) a time in the future from the date it was executed?

I have looked at the NPM packages `date-fns` and `moment` but they do not seem to cater to what I am looking for.

I guess you could do a RegExp?

Comment: _"I guess you could do a RegExp"_  no, you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guess correctly. For future reference, you're likely to get better answers if you try to solve the problem yourself and post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of anything you have problems with.

Coming on Stack Overflow and asking a question is more work than googling 'javascript regex' after all, for all involved.

```
var date = new Date();
var s = '1hr 30m 4s';
var re = /((\d+)hr)?( (\d+)m)?( (\d+)s)?/m;
var match = re.exec(s);
if (match != null) {
    if (typeof(match[2]) !== 'undefined') {
        date.setHours( date.getHours() + parseInt(match[2]) );
    }
    if (typeof(match[4]) !== 'undefined') {
        date.setMinutes( date.getMinutes() + parseInt(match[4]) );
    }
    if (typeof(match[6]) !== 'undefined') {
        date.setSeconds( date.getSeconds() + parseInt(match[6]) );
    }
}
console.log(date);
```

Comment: You should probably make the spaces before minutes / seconds optional to handle intervals without all three parts, eg `"5m 1s"`

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned Moment.js, I would recommend using their [Durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) with an [ISO 8601 time interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) format, ie "PT1H30M4S".

This format can be parsed not only by Moment.js but many other languages and libraries (hooray for standards).

Your current string isn't too far off and can be transformed quite easily.

For example

```js
const durationString = '1hr 30m 4s'

const iso8601TimeInterval = 'PT' + durationString
    .replace(/hr/ig, 'h') // replace "hr" with "h"
    .replace(/\s/g, '')   // remove the spaces
    .toUpperCase()        // uppercase
console.log('Time interval:', iso8601TimeInterval)

const duration = moment.duration(iso8601TimeInterval)
const now = moment()

console.info('Now:', now.format())
console.info('Then:', now.add(duration).format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This should work with just about any duration string you throw at it, as long as it's only made up of hours ("hr"), minutes ("m") and seconds ("s").

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. I have considered at least seconds should be available. You need to extract out the 2nd, 4th and 6th group for hr, min and sec respectively.

`((\d{1,2})hr)?.((\d{1,2})m)?.((\d{1,2})s)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of:

```js
var d="1hr 30m 4s"
var ds =d.split(/hr |m |s/)
var dnow=new Date()
var dlater= new Date()
dlater.setTime( dnow.getTime() + ( ds[2]*1 + ds[1]*60 + ds[0]* 3600) * 1000)

console.log("now",dnow);
console.log("later",dlater);
```